# PhotoKit delete photos,how to change the language of title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, photokit

I'm just use the PhotoKit to delete photos, just like this:

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets: arrayOfPHAssets];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
}];
```

And the result is:[delete image's info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4nKa.jpg)

How to change the title's language to Chinese.
I have a try to change iPhone's language and it doesn't matter.Please.

Comment: Is your app localized to Chinese?

Comment: The both , Chinese and English. But I don't know how to change the title's language.

Comment: I see an "Edit" button in that screenshot. Your app is running in English, not Chinese. Once you get localization working properly you should not see any English in your app if the device's language is set to Chinese.

Comment: I have set the localizations, and the edit button's title is Chinese, but the alert view, also is the english. The demo's url is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575,and you can have a try.

Comment: It's depends on the system language, once set the language, and the should restart the iPhone. Thanks.